# How to properly set up subqueries using Business Objects GUI

Tags: business-objects

We have a table of events, and I wish to find the most recent event for each client at the query level (i.e. not a filter/function in the report level), to feed into another query.

I can do this by editing the SQL and adding a subquery by hand:

```sql
SELECT
  ...
FROM
  ...
  Events,
  (SELECT Client_ID, MAX(Date) AS Date
   FROM Events
   GROUP BY Client_ID) Latest_Event
WHERE
  ...
  AND Events.Client_ID = Latest_Event.Client_ID
  AND Events.Date = Latest_Event.Date
```

How do I do this in the Query Panel GUI?

This is SAP BusinessObjects BI Platform 4.2, Version 14.2

Comment: I don't see a way to do this short of doing something at the universe level. You could add a MAX(Date) object to the universe or even put the SQL you have above in a derived table in the data foundation layer of your universe.

Comment: Ah, that's good to know - I don't have access to edit the universe so filtering with hand-written SQL is possibly the best/only option here.